# How to fix: "SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data"

Tags: json, react-native

I'm working with React-Native right now, trying to pass formdata to a backend php-file as JSON. But everytime the form is submitted the console shows the following error "SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data". With firefox I checked the request and response under network.

Under request it shows the JSON correctly, under response it shows the JSON correctly. 1 thing that stands out is that under `Headers`, it says that response `Content-Type` is `text/html` and that request `Content-Type` is `text/plain`. Could that be causing the issue? I wouldn't know what else to do since I already specify the `Content-Type` in the code.

Google Chrome says `.then(response => response.json())` is causing the error.

```
await fetch('http://192.168.2.16/React-Native/endpoint.php', {
        method: 'POST',
        header: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          intensiteit: intensiteit,
          soortStank: soort,
          latitude: lat,
          longitude: long,
          buurt: neighbourhood,
        }),
        mode: 'no-cors', 
      })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(responseJson => {
        Alert.alert(JSON.stringify(responseJson));
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
      });
```

The php-file:

```
$obj = file_get_contents('php://input');
$obj = json_decode($obj, true);
$result['soort'] = $obj['soortStank'];
echo json_encode($result);
```

And yes I looked at other posts, but they didn't help sadly. I also tried adding `dataType: 'json',` in there, but that didnt help.

Comment: This error is from your php file. it is returning data in wrong format (as expected by fetch) Check "RESPONSE" in "NETWORK" tab , select XHR only to clear the clutter.

Comment: @AliJibran I have added the code in the phpfile in case you wanted to take a look

Comment: @AliJibran This is the response it gives back: https://gyazo.com/a6d29b78bf2e8fa2cafa88137f9294ed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The request from your front-end app to the back-end endpoint is a cross-origin request. Adding `mode: 'no-cors'` to the fetch request doesn't change this, so remove it to begin with.

Next, the php endpoint must include some header declarations to allow the cross-origin request to succeed.

Add the following to the top of the php file, replacing the `http://localhost:9999` part with the origin you are sending the request from. When testing locally, it'll likely be identical apart from the port number. When running in production, be sure to replace it with the correct origin for your front-end app eg. `https://www.example-app.com`.

```
header("Allow-Access-Control-Origin: http://localhost:9999");
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

This should work.

Comment: Don't have to reply to this rn, but the check with the `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` and the `Allow-Acces-Control-Origin` gives those same 3 error's :'). I'll be using the `*` for now.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely a problem of null values.

Replace null values with empty strings in the `body`.

Perhaps, you also just need to change the php file to:

```
$obj = file_get_contents('php://input');
$obj = json_decode($obj, true);
$result['soort'] = $obj['soortStank'] ?? '';
echo json_encode($result);
```